# Text truncated afeter beign pushed by a button using hover CSS

Tags: css, animation, text, hover, truncate

I'm trying to make an animation with css. A sort of button that translate from right to left when hover. And doing that it will "push" a div containing text. So when this div shrink enough the text will be truncated and the 3 dots will appear. I hope I am clear enough.  tried to solv it with flex but the text doesn't want to be pushed away !!! Here is the code :

html :

```
<div class="menus">
  <div class="namePlat">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="price">
    <p>25€</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="check">
      <img src="img/check24.png" alt="#">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

css :

```
.price {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
  top: 2em;
  width: 10%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}

.box {
  transform-origin: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  color: green;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 1000ms;
  .check {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30%;
    top: 35%;
    margin: auto;
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transition: transform 1500ms ease-in-out;
  }
}

.namePlat {
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  p,
  h3 {
    max-width: 400px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}

.menus {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover>.box {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    .check {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
  }
  &:hover>.price {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    transform: translateX(-5em);
  }
  &:hover>.namePlat {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    p,
    h3 {
      max-width: 400px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you edit your question's snippets, put the HTML & CSS code together in the one snippet. theres 3 boxes in the snippet editor; each for html, css and javascript, that way we can actually run the code and see it all being applied.

Comment: @Jasmine sorry I didn't mean snippets. Juste a simple part of the code. I've rectfied it.